# strlen inconsistent with zero length string

Tags: c, strlen, datastage

I'm creating a DataStage parallel routine, which is a C or C++ function that is called from within IBM (formerly Ascential) DataStage. It is failing if one of the strings passed in is zero length. If I put this at the very first line of the function:

```
return strlen(str);
```

then it returns 0 for the calls that pass in empty values into str. If I put this at the first line, however...

```
if (strlen(str)==0) {return 0;}
```

then it does not return and goes into an infinite loop

I'm baffled - it works fine in a test harness, but not in DataStage.

Maybe there is something odd about the way DataStage passes empty strings to C routines?

```
int pxStrFirstCharList(char *str, char *chars )
{
  if (strlen(str)==0) {return 0;}
  if (strlen(chars)==0) {return 0;}
  int i = 0;
  //Start search
  while (str[i]) //for the complete input string
  {
    if (strchr(chars, str[i]))
    {
      return i+1;
    }
    ++i;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure neither of the arguments could be `NULL` IIRC, `strlen()` invokes UB when called with `NULL` arguments.

Comment: Just a guess, is the function perhaps getting multi-byte characters  passed via such pointers?

Answer (score 1):

There is a builtin function for what you are doing, it's called `strcspn`. This function takes two strings, and searches the first one for the first occurance of any of the characters of the second string.

I suggest using that than RYO...

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcspn/

Comment: +1 if you linked to a good reference rather than one of the most error-filled references on the net.

Comment: @R.. hehe, I'm pretty sure the above page is error free, TBH, `man strcspn` is really the best option!

Comment: I doubt that one has errors (the function is sufficiently simple), but I cringe everytime I see folks giving that awful site pagerank...

Comment: Thanks for that, I might use that within my function to replace the core logic but I have to wrap it in order that I can link it in to DataStage.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
int pxStrFirstCharList(char *str, char *chars )
{
  if (str && chars && (0 != strlen(str)) && (0 != strlen(chars)))
  {
    int i = 0;
    //Start search
    while (str[i]) //for the complete input string
    {
      if (strchr(chars, str[i]))
      {
        return i+1;
      }
      ++i;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Also, I don't quite get the point of the `while` loop ... (and no, I don't mean that this could be written as `for`). What I mean is that on one hand you are doing a search (`strstr`) that itself will be implemented as a loop and still you have some outer loop. Could it be that you actually wanted to have `chars` in its place, i.e.:

```
int pxStrFirstCharList(char *str, char *chars )
{
  if (str && chars && (0 != strlen(str)) && (0 != strlen(chars)))
  {
    int i = 0;
    //Start search
    while (chars[i]) //for the complete input string
    {
      if (strchr(str, chars[i]))
      {
        return i+1;
      }
      ++i;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

...? That is, look for each of the characters within `chars` inside the string denoted by `str` ...

Comment: No, it needs to loop through `str` to find the first character that is in `chars` and not the other way around. You may be right about null-testing the parameters but I'm fairly sure that DataStage does not pass nulls. I'll update here if I find otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

If NULL is not explicitly part of the game, at least during development phase, it's always a good idea to add a precondition check on pointers received by a function:

```
int pxStrFirstCharList(char *str, char *chars )
{
  if (!str)
    return -1;

  if (!chars)
    return -2;
....
```

(The negative values -1 and -2 than tell the caller that something went wrong)

Or doing it in a more relaxed way, silently accepting NULL pointer strings as ""-string:

```
int pxStrFirstCharList(char *str, char *chars )
{
  if (!str)
    return 0;

  if (!chars)
    return 0;
...
```

If you are the only one using this API you could `#ifndef BUILD_RELEASE` these checks away for a release build if anything is tested stable.

Comment: The `assert` macro already exists for this purpose and it's a much better debugging aid since it aborts the program rather than continuing with erroneous state once an error is detected.

Comment: Phil, you may want to comment on this answer instead of appending your reply to the post itself, and then mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is the strlen's issue when the length of the string is 0. For example,

char s1[0];
char *s2="a";

printf("%d %s\n", sizeof(s1), s1);//0    @

printf("%d %s\n", strlen(s1), s1);//3    @

printf("%d %s\n", sizeof(s2), s2);//8 a

printf("%d %s\n", strlen(s2), s2);// 1 a

You will get a weird answer for using strlen and you can check its source code in detail([https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strlen.c.html](http://[1]:%20https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strlen.c.html)). In nutshell, you can use sizeof instead of strlen for char string or avoid 0 length case by using strlen.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to this for better presenting your question/answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/3519504